# Union of a power set with itself, and count the number of unique sets that contain at least one token

Tags: set-theory

Sorry in advance if I am butchering the set theory or probability vocabulary...

I am trying to normalize a programming problem I encountered - and hopefully find a solution.

1. The problem begins with a set $C$ of $n$ letter types, e.g. $C =\{a,b,c\}$.
2. We take the power set of C $P(C) = \{a,b,c\}, 
   \{a,b\}, .... \{c\}, \{\}$, its cardinal is $2^n$.
3. Then we generate all the unions of the letter-tokens of every subset of $P(C)$ with itself. I don't know how it's properly called, but it looks like a $2^n$ x $2^n$ matrix with both row and columns names being the elements of $P(C)$ and each cell merges these elements: so the top left corner is $ \{a, a, b, b, c, c\}$ and the bottom right corner is the empty set $\{\}$. Yes, the elements are duplicated (that's why I switched from letter type to letter token).
4. And now we want to count how many unique multisets contain at least one letter-token of every letter-category (meaning, we would discard $\{b,b,c\}$ because it does not contain any token $a$).

I have gone as far as I can in terms of formalism, and I would need help polishing the mathematical description of the problem. Also I still I don't know how to generalize the solution for any number of letter type, so any guidance on that would be awesome :)

[EDIT]
One important thing is that there are redundancies when merging the sets of the superset the  that I'm also interested in counting.
For example:

- $\{a,a,b,b,c,c\}$ is not redundant because it can only arise from merging $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{a,b,c\}$
- $\{a,b,c\}$ is 8 times redundant, as it can arise from merging $\{a,b,c\}$ with $\{\}$, or $\{a,b\}$ with $\{c\}$ etc etc ...

Consequently I am both interested in

- the total number of "admissible"/"comnpatible" pairs (that is $3^n$ thanks to the comments and answers)
- and also count the number of unique sets/multisets (I don't really know how to name those)

Comment: So corresponding to a subset $A$, the subsets which would be "admissible" are the ones containing $A^c$. So the number of possible sets are $2^{|A|}$. So in total 
$$\sum_{A\subset P([n])}2^{|A|}=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k=3^n$$

Comment: Aw! What is $A^c$ ?

Comment: The complement of $A$.

Comment: That is SO smart oO

Comment: @shadow10 It's possible to avoid the need to take the sum.  See my answer below.

Comment: @RobertShore this is even smarter, +1!

Comment: What you're building is more like a "product" than a "union".

Comment: Nice! So one thing is that the solution gives the number of compatible sets, but there are redundancies I am interested into counting - I added the "unicity" word in my (poor) description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in the comments works.  Here's another way to look at it.  You want the number of ordered pairs $(A, B)$ such that $A \cup B = C$.  That means for each element $x \in C$, we have exactly one of the three situations $x \in A \setminus B, x \in B \setminus A,$ or $x \in A \cap B$.  Moreover, knowing which case we're in for each $x \in C$ uniquely specifies $A$ and $B$.

For each of the $n$ elements in $C$ there are exactly $3$ choices, so there are $3^n$ ordered pairs $(A, B)$ such that $A \cup B=C$.

I prefer this solution because it avoids the need to take any sums.

Comment: Wonderful! That is I think the first piece of the puzzle! But now there are redundancies across these 3^n sets: for example {a,a,b,b,c,c} is not redundant because it can only arise from merging {a,b,c} and {a,b,c}, but {a,b,c} is 8 times redundant, as it can arise from merging {a,b,c} with {}, or {a,b} with {c} etc etc ... I don't know how explain it better :$

Comment: @WaterFox Let $k$ be the number of elements appearing once in a particular multiset.  Then that multiset appears $2^k$ times in your collection, because each singleton must choose between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: oooh. I see how the process works when I apply it to my example, but I can't find a way to infer how $3^n$ collapses to the number of unique multiset in the general case. I mean I could loop over every multiset, but ... :/

Comment: I'm not understanding your question now.  But in the general case, there will be $m$ elements that appear in a multiset once and $n-m$ elements that appear in it twice.  Each such multiset (for each $m$ there will be $\binom nm$ of them) will occur with multiplicity $2^m$ and as noted in the comment above, using the binomial theorem to expand $(1+2)^n$ shows that $\overset{n}{\underset{m=1}{\sum}} \binom nm 2^m=3^n$.

Comment: Aw sorry for poorly explaining. If I get $n$ letters and its power set, I now know there are $3^n$ compatible sets. If I get a multiset you explained how to find its multiplicity in the matrix, but I don't understand how I can get the number of "groups" in the matrix (sounds like the reverse problem?)

Comment: Oh I see you edited your comment! Thank you SO much!

Comment: Also concerning the binomial expansion, I think you meant $\sum_{m=0}^{n}{...}$

Comment: @WaterFox You're correct, I did.

Comment: Yay! Awesome! In the meantime and thanks to your answers I could go (and get stuck) a bit further adding probabilities to this problem :p See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4634751/1146035)