# Probabilities of the elements of a Cartesian square

Tags: probability

My problem is the following:

- We consider a set $C$ of $n$ letters, e.g. $\{a,b,c\}$.
- We consider the random process of forming sets by independently selecting each letter $i \in C$ with probability $p_i$.
- This process generates elements of the power set $P(C) = \{a,b,c\}, \{a,b\} ... \{\}$ (that we can encode $\{1,1,1\}, \{1,1,0\}, ... \{0,0,0\}$) with probability $p_ap_bp_c, ~ p_ap_b(1-p_c) ... (1-p_a)(1-p_b)(1-p_c)$.
- Then we sample two subsets in $P(C)$ according to their probability and we merge their elements to form a multiset. This process generates the cartesian square $P(C)xP(C)$ with $2^{2n}$ multisets. For example, drawing $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{c\}$ generates $\{a,b,c,c\}$ (equivalently $\{1,1,2\}$).
- What I can not figure out is how I can start from $\{a,b,c,c\}$ equivalently $\{1,1,2\}$ (or any other outcome) and express its probability under the process I stated.

I tried a bunch of expressions, but they inconveniently never summed to 1 :/
I believe my error comes from "forgetting" that when I start from $\{a,b,c,c\}$, it's not like I can sample letters as I want: I am actually sampling already-formed aggregations of letters in P(C).

Note: I am trying to expand on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4631282/union-of-a-power-set-with-itself-and-count-the-number-of-unique-sets-that-conta).

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a random variable $\ell$ indicating length of the set in $P(C)$ and calculate the probability $g_i$ that size of the picked set is $\ell=i$. Your problem arises from the fact that $\{a\},....,\{n\}$ has probabilities summing to $1$. So now room for probabilities for the sets $\{a,b\}$ so that probabilities sum to $1$.

Now calculate the probability of $\{a,b\}$ as $p_a p_b g_2$ where we have $g_2$ since the set of size $2$.

Regarding going from $P(C)$ to $P(C) \times P(C)$, if you do the above then $P(C) \times P(C)$ also will have probabilities summing to $1$ but you should calculate the probabilities slightly differently. Probability of $\{a,b,c,c\}$ is probability of $\{a,b,c\} \times \{c\}$  + probability of $\{c\} \times \{a,b,c\}$ + probability $\{a,c\} \times \{b,c\}$ + probability $\{b,c\} \times \{a,c\}$ $  = p_ap_bp_c g_3 p_c g_1 + p_c g_1 p_ap_bp_c g_3 + p_a p_c g_2 p_b p_c g_2 + p_b p_c g_2 p_a p_c g_2$ i.e., consider different ways you will end up with $\{a,b,c,c\}$ and sum their probabilities.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I am not sure to understand why $\{a\} ... \{n\}$ would have to sum to 1 ?

Comment: I am saying if you have a set $\{1,...,n\}$ with probability of choosing $i$ equal to $p_i$ with $\sum_i p_i = 1$ then what you should do is form the probability of $\{i,j\}$ as $p_i p_j g_2$ then probabilities will sum to $1$. If $\sum_i p_i \neq 1$ then normalize the probabilities by the sum and then apply $g_i$. This will give what you want i.e., probabilities will sum to $1$.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check it out.